# Validate number in express validator nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I realize that when using express validator, there is a different between 2 codes below

```
check('isActive', 'isActive is number 0 or 1').optional({ checkFalsy : false, nullable : false }).isInt().isIn([0, 1])
```

and

```
check('isActive', 'isActive is number 0 or 1').optional({ checkFalsy : false, nullable : false }).isInt({ min:0,max:1 })
```

With the first one, I can not enter input such as 00001, however it can run with the second one.
So I have a question that how to check 1,3,5,9 with input likes 0001, 0003, 0005 or 0009 for example ?

Thank for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using string as the value and use regex pattern to check the string is a number.

Example

`Joi.string().pattern(/^[0-9]+$/)`

If there is any other specific rules add that to `custom` function. Here I'm adding an example to verify the number is less than 9.

**Schema**

```
Joi.object({
  number: Joi.string().pattern(/^[0-9]+$/).required().custom((value, helper) => {
            if (Number(value) > 9) {
                return helper.message("Number must be less than 9")
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }),
})
```

**Data to validate**

```
{ 
 number: "0009",
}
```

Test it out here https://joi.dev/tester/